# android studio adding package

Tags: android-studio, libs

I try to add [android httposter package](https://github.com/licryle/HTTPPoster)
i do exactly the readme file but i get all the time error for

> Error:(30, 0) Project with path ':libs:HttpPoster' could not be found in project ':app'.
>   Open File

i also tried to change into HttpPost etc.

what does he mean with symbolic link i understoot this like just a link to that project see picture
[directory myproject/libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBHST.png)

thanks by advance

Comment: post your module's build.gradle file

Comment: https://github.com/licryle/HTTPPoster/blob/master/library/build.gradle

Comment: I added the project via import module now module is compiled and could import from everywhere in the project.